# mysql stored procedure variable error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi I am finding my way round MySQL trying to migrate data from MSsql for the first time.  I have created a stored procedure that clear all the tables down so I can import the data repeatedly as I test and alter things.  I thought I had this pretty well figured but I am unsure how to get the actual value of the variable to go with the delete statement.  Thanks for any assistance

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE ClearData ()
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_TableName varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

-- declare cursor for list of tables to clear
DEClARE TableToRemove CURSOR FOR 

SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where table_type ='BASE TABLE';

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

OPEN TableToRemove;

ClearData: LOOP

FETCH TableToRemove INTO v_TableName;

IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
LEAVE ClearData;
END IF;

--This is the problem how do I get the value of v_TableName 
delete from `v_TableName`;


END LOOP ClearData;

CLOSE TableToRemove;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to use [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: I have some non standard table names ie debit info   how do I enclose them with a ` ?

Comment: One option would be to use [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat): `... CONCAT('\`', v_TableName, '\`') ...`